# spring.rabbitmq.addresses : load balancer address vs list of nodes addresses

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I can't find in the recent documentation the pros/cons of using a loadbalancer instead of a list of nodes when setting

```
spring.rabbitmq.addresses
```

why it's better to use the list of nodes instead of loadbalancer?

My rabbitmq cluster (3 nodes) is consumed by 40 spring boot applications, and around 500 queues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, only a single connection is opened, so a load balancer won't really do much for you, unless you change the `CachingConnectionFactory` `CacheMode` to `CONNECTION`.

The list of addresses is so the client can fail over to another broker without the need for a load balancer.